# Get the text in the image description of a tweet using rtweet

Tags: r, rtweet

Is there a way to get the text used as the image description of tweets? I'm using the  package, which allows one to get several pieces of information about a tweet (text, links, hashtags etc) but I can't get this info.

`{rtweet}` allows one to post a tweet with `rtweet::post_tweet` and add the image descriptio through the parameter `media_alt_text` but I can't find this information when I download a tweet using the `rtweet::get_timeline` function.

#### reprex

```
library(rtweet)

# parsing the tweet data
last_tweet_parsed <- rtweet::get_timeline(user = 'esquinadobrasil', 
                                          n = 1, 
                                          parse = T)

head(last_tweet_parsed)

# not parsing the tweet data
last_tweet_unparsed <- rtweet::get_timeline(user = 'esquinadobrasil', 
                                   n = 1, 
                                   parse = F)

temp_df <- as.data.frame(last_tweet_unparsed)
head(temp_df)
```

Comment: Does the tweet you used as an example have an image description? If so, what is it? My first guess was this, but I didn't see anything:
`last_tweet_parsed %>% pull(entities) %>% map(function(twt) {twt$media$ext_alt_text})`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, all tweets from this @ account <<https://twitter.com/esquinadobrasil>> use a number as the "media_alt_text"

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to do this using `get_timeline`. Would it be possible to generate a custom query and then ask for the media objects? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/media. That's not something I've done before.

Answer (score 1):

Using v2 API is much more flexible and sync. with documentation.

Demo Tweet. one of tweet from `esquinadobrasil`
I will shows how to get  image alt text.

```
https://twitter.com/esquinadobrasil/status/1615009611186069504
```

I will get `red box` text (`alt_text` of image)

```
sort 893
```

[image]

#### Demo

```
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
require(dplyr)

bearer_token <- "***** your bearer_token *****"
headers <- c(`Authorization` = sprintf('Bearer %s', bearer_token))

params <- list(`expansions` = 'attachments.media_keys',
               `media.fields` = 'public_metrics,url,alt_text')

tweet_id <- "1615009611186069504"
url_handle <-
  sprintf('https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/%s', tweet_id)

response <-
  httr::GET(url = url_handle,
            httr::add_headers(.headers = headers),
            query = params)
obj <- httr::content(response, as = "text")
print(obj)
```

#### Run & Result

```
$ rscript get-image.R

[1] "{\"data\":{\"attachments\":{\"media_keys\":[\"3_1615009514297729024\"]},\"text\":\"Municipio: Santo Antônio Da
Platina - PR\\nSetor censitário: 412410305000028\\nPopulação: 718\\nÁrea (Km2): 1.31\\nDensidade (hab/Km2): 548.06\\
nZona: urbana\\n\\uD83D\\uDDFA https://xxx/KagyCLHLrM https://xxx/z1YDyTJArx\",\"id\":\"1615009611186069504\",\"ed
it_history_tweet_ids\":[\"1615009611186069504\"]},\"includes\":{\"media\":[{\"media_key\":\"3_1615009514297729024\",
\"url\":\"https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FmmqmLiXoAAdEmw.jpg\",\"alt_text\":\"sort 893\",\"type\":\"photo\"}]}}"
```

[image]

#### Main Idea

V2 [Get Tweet](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/lookup/api-reference/get-tweets-id) by ID

```
GET /2/tweets/:id
```

[image]

One of query parameter `media.fields`  can get the `alt_text` from documentation.
[image]

I tested the same API by Postman.

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/1615009611186069504/?expansions=attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url,alt_text
```

I can get the same Result

[image]